# Reactjs Retrieve ID of element after POST

Tags: reactjs, express

I want to create an item in a database based on the data retrieved from a simple form. Basically, after the user clicks `submit` this function is ran:

```
createItem(item){
        this.state.bucket_list.push({
            name: item,
            isCompleted: false
        });
        this.setState({bucket_list: this.state.bucket_list});

        // POST to DB
        fetch(url(this.props.api), {
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: item,
                isCompleted:false
            })
        });

    }
```

The object is successfully created and I have modified the state which will cause a re-render. However, only the `name` and `isCompleted` property of the object is set. There is also an `id` that automatically gets generated after the insert by the database provider. This `id` is important because I need it for my `deletes and updates` calls. So I need something like this.

```
createItem(item){
        // POST to DB first and get ID of newly created object
        fetch(url(this.props.api), {
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: item,
                isCompleted:false
            })
        }).then(function(data){
           id = data.id; // get ID
           this.state.bucket_list.push({
              id: id,
              name: item,
              isCompleted: false
           });
           this.setState({bucket_list: this.state.bucket_list});
        });

    }
```

Also my API code written in node.js (express framework):

```
.post(function (req, res) {
    let item = new BucketList();
    item.name = req.body.name;
    item.isCompleted = req.body.isCompleted ? req.body.isCompleted : false;
    item.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        res.json({message:"Item Sucessfully Added", item});
    });
})
```

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question.... but maybe I know what you're saying..

Comment: I need to get the object back and get the appropriate `id` so I can append to my state `bucketlist` but I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: ya, I can see that, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for that id on the top-level of your response, but your response is an object with two keys: message and item.  Inside the item, you should find the id, so change:

```
id = data.id; // get ID
```

to:

```
id = data.item.id; // get ID
```

And, better yet, you could replace that line altogether along with the push line to be something like:(this is the entire code of your "then" block)

```
this.setState({bucket_list: [...this.state.bucket_list, data.item]});
```

This way, you're not modifying state, then covering for the fact that you modified state, you're just using setState to properly set the bucket_list to the contents of the old bucket list plus the new item.

of course, this uses the array spread operator, so you need that available in whatever javascript version you're using.